# How to perform a multi-byte safe SQL REGEXP query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following SQL query to find the dictionary words that contain specific letters.

It's working fine in the English dictionary:

```
SELECT word
FROM english_dictionary
WHERE word REGEXP '[abcdef]'
```

But running the same query on Slovak dictionary, which includes UTF8 special accented letters don't work.

```
SELECT word
FROM slocak_dictionary
WHERE word REGEXP '[áäčďéóú]'
```

I've searched everywhere, can't find the answer to this issue. If I use LIKE, it's working, but the query is getting very ugly:

```
SELECT word
FROM slocak_dictionary
WHERE 
word LIKE '%á%'
AND word LIKE '%ä%'
AND word LIKE '%č%'
AND word LIKE '%ď%'
AND word LIKE '%é%'
AND word LIKE '%ó%'
AND word LIKE '%ú%'
```

Because I deal with many letters that need to be excluded or includes in the query, breaking it down like this is not very elegant.

Is there any way to perform a multi-byte safe SQL REGEXP query on MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB has better support of REGEXP.

In MySQL, this will test for `word` having any of those accented characters:

```
HEX(word) REGEXP '^(..)*(C3A1|C3A4|C48D|C48F|C3A9|C3B3|C3BA)'
```

The `^(..)*` is to make sure the subsequent test is byte (2 hex chars) aligned.

You can see those utf8 encodings by doing something like

```
SELECT HEX('áäčďéóú');
```

(Your attempt with `LIKE` should have said `OR` instead of `AND`.)